# How to change the serializer of WebMethod parameters

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, serialization, json.net

Ive discovered an issue in some of our old web code. The problem is that the default serializer isnt serializing the date properly. I want to use JSON.Net in order to serialize the parameters for the web methods in our aspx code. But im not sure how to tell it to use JSON.NET instead of using the default serializer.

Here is an example snipit of our code

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function EditApplication(ByVal Application As ApplicationModel, ByVal Country As String, ByVal Language As String) As jsonResponse
        Dim r As New jsonResponse
        Dim g As New ApplicationRequest
        g.country = Country
        g.locale = Language
        g.platform = "Android"
        g.timestamp = ""
        g.transactionid = "abc123"
        ....
```

So I need ApplicationModel to serialize using JSON.Net. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be helpful (since this is taken from the REST web service) but you can define it on OperationContract like this one below:
**System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json**

```
<OperationContract()> _
<WebGet(responseformat:=System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
```